# How to map a dictionary from a .py file

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a .py file with nothing but python dictionaries in it.  I import the .py file into my working script.  I want to loop through each dictionary and map the values to a dataframe.  When I try, the Or even how to get a list of the dictionaries from the file.  Could someone show me how to loop through objects in a .py file after importing that file into another script.  Below are some dictionaries to use.

Let us assume the below dictionary is saved to `mc.py`

```
ds_ad_affinity = {0:1.0000,1:0.9800}

ds_ak_alliance = {0:1.0000, 1:0.9500}

ds_fp_paid_in_full = {'eligiable -does not have discount':1.0000,
                      'ineligable': 1.0000,
                      'eligiable-has discount': 0.9500}
```

I then try:

```
import mc

for i in factor_list:
    col_name = i+"factors"
    bi[col_name]=bi[i].map(dir(mc.i))
    print(bi[col_name].head())
```

And I also try:

```
for i in factor_list:
        col_name = i+"factors"
        bi[col_name]=bi[i].map(mc.i)
        print(bi[col_name].head())
```

But I get the following error:

AttributeError: module 'mc' has no attribute 'i'.  In this case, the names of the dictionaries are the same as the names of the columns i'm using as the keys to map the dictionary values.  So there is a column names `ds_ad_affinity`  and the result should be column named `ds_ad_affinity_factors` with the values from `ds_ad_affinity` dictionary.

Comment: ```from mc import ds_ad_affinity, ds_ak_alliance, ds_fp_paid_in_full```

Comment: `mc.i` is asking for the literal attribute `i`. You probably want `getattr(mc, i)`